# How can I map tuple key with df values updating an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to map a column of my df with a dictionary. My dictionary contains tuple as key and I want to update an existing column value based on the key. How can I achieve that ?

sample df

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
 None     123     test    999     42
```

sample dict

```
{(123, "test", 999):1}
```

final df

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
     1     123     test    999      42
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried and explain what doesn’t work so we can help. We aren’t here to write it for you…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series with MultiIndex` by keys, convert columns in same order like keys by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
d = {(123, "test", 999):1}
s = pd.Series(d)

s1 = df.set_index(['column2','column3','column4'])['column1']
s1.update(s)

df = s1.reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
  column1  column2 column3  column4
0       1      123    test      999
```

EDIT: If there is multple columns:

```
print (df)
  column1  column2 column3  column4  column5
0    None      123    test      999       42
1    None      123    test       99       42


d = {(123, "test", 999):1}
s = pd.Series(d)

s1 = df.set_index(['column2','column3','column4'])['column1']
s1.update(s)

df['column1'] = s1.reset_index()['column1']
print (df)
  column1  column2 column3  column4  column5
0     1.0      123    test      999       42
1    None      123    test       99       42
```

EDIT1: If set `name` in `Series s`, is possible only set MultiIndex:

```
d = {(123, "test", 999):1}
s = pd.Series(d, name='column1')

df1 = df.set_index(['column2','column3','column4'])
df1.update(s)

df = df1.reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
  column1  column2 column3  column4  column5
0     1.0      123    test      999       42
1    None      123    test       99       42
```

This solution overwrite existing values in `col1`, if need replace missing values `NaN` or `None`s use:

```
#because 7 in first column not overwritten value
print (df)
   column1  column2 column3  column4
0        7      123    test      999

d = {(123, "test", 999):1}
s = pd.Series(d)

df1 = (df.set_index(['column2','column3','column4'])['column1']
         .fillna(s)
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df1)
   column1  column2 column3  column4
0        7      123    test      999
```

First solution set `1`:

```
s1 = df.set_index(['column2','column3','column4'])['column1']
s1.update(s)

df2 = s1.reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df2)
   column1  column2 column3  column4
0        1      123    test      999
```